# Angular (scope?) issues in a Directive that requires the parent FormController

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

This is a contrived example, but one that demonstrates an issue I'm encountering.

I have a form that has an input that is generated using a directive. The code looks similar to the following. fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/technicolorenvy/CFynn/2/

View

```
    <div ng-controller="AppController">
        <form name="myForm">
            <input name="myInput" id="myInput" ng-model="myInputModel" ng-pattern="/\d+/" my-directive required/>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="submitForm()">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Controller

```
    app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.submitForm = function () {
            console.log('form controller inside AppController submitForm()');
            console.log(angular.copy($scope.myForm));
            console.log('is the form valid? ' + $scope.myForm.$valid);
            console.log(' ');
        };
    });
```

Directive

```
    app.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            template: '<div><input/></div>',
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '^form',
            compile: function (element, attrs) {
                // some setup here
                // move the id and ng-model down onto the enclosed input
                element.removeAttr('id').removeAttr('ng-model').removeAttr('name');
                element.find('input').attr('id', attrs.id).attr('ng-model', attrs.ngModel).attr('name', attrs.name);

                var inputName = attrs.name,
                    $input = element.find('input');
                if (attrs.required) {
                    element.removeAttr('required');
                    $input.attr('required', true);
                }
                if (attrs.ngPattern) {
                    element.removeAttr('ng-pattern');
                    $input.attr('ng-pattern', attrs.ngPattern);
                }

                return {
                    pre: function (scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
                        var patternErrs,
                        fakeNum = 1234;

                        $input.on('change', function () {
                            patternErrs = formCtrl.$error.pattern;
                            if (patternErrs && patternErrs.length > 0) {
                                angular.forEach(patternErrs, function (err) {
                                    if (err.$name === inputName) {
                                        $input.val(fakeNum);
                                        formCtrl[inputName].$setViewValue(fakeNum);
                                        formCtrl[inputName].$setValidity('pattern', true);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            console.log('formCtrl inside directive');
                            console.log(angular.copy(formCtrl));
                            console.log('is the form valid? ' + formCtrl.$valid);
                            console.log(' ');
                        });
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

In the directive I have an onChange event on the 'generated' input that checks for pattern errors matching this input's name, then if there are any, force the data to be what we need with a fake value, using `setViewValue` and then set the validity using `setValidity`.

This works... sort of. The problem is, on the FIRST submit, the form is always invalid. You must click submit TWICE for the form to be considered valid. (steps included below)

1. Enter a string (eg 'abcd') in the input
2. The input fails pattern validation, then gets a valid value (1234)
3. the directive 'myDirective' handles this + sets the input's value and validity
4. On FIRST sumbit, however, the form is invalid
5. On SECOND submit, with no change to input, the form is valid

So How do I make the form valid on the first submit WITHOUT strongarming the form's validity (read, I don't want manually set the form to be valid). This feels like a scoping issue, but if it is, I'm not too sure how to remedy it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `scope.$apply()` in your change event once you're done altering scope.

That said.. **I'm not sure what you're attempting to do here.**

It seems like you might be trying to solve a simple problem in a complicated way. It's fairly apparent the code isn't very testable. Perhaps some of what's being done is actually "business logic" that could be encapsulated in a controller?

What is the exact goal of here?

Comment: Again, super contrived example.

the real-world case is this.

I have a directive that will create inputs that use the bs-datepicker directive. the catch is, by default, bs-datepicker comes in somewhat hot and will update the elements value attribute to the current day if the invalid text is entered.

After that, bs-datepicker will add a date collection to the formController.$error and input.$error collections. But the UI is bad. As it _looks_ like you have valid input.

My take was to go with the 'default' UI provided by bs-datepicker, but actually massage it in a way that is a valid

Comment: based on the above, is this still a gross way to do this?

Comment: Hmm, that's tricky... You may be better off altering the bsdatepicker directive to suit your needs. It might be as simple as changing it's priority, or maybe reordering the validation functions in the ngModel $parsers and $formatters. My gut tells me that anytime you have a directive just to shuffle around attributes and trick another directive, you *might* be barking up the wrong tree. In the end though, whatever works is best. However whatever is *testable* and works is *even better*.

Answer (score 1):

That code inside your $input.on('change') is never digested... that is, Angular never knew to run all its watches and internal procedures after your change event. So it runs it during the first digest, which happens the first time you run Submit.

I think if you wrapped that bit in a $timeout() or used $scope.$apply() it'd resolve the issue.

Comment: Angular doesn't "digest code". When a $digest occurs, the scope is examined for changes and $watch handlers are fired. That function in `$input.on('change', HERE)` is just a handler for a DOM event.

Comment: alternately could use `ng-change` , which angular will watch